# Routing using button click function in Angular Js 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm angular js 2 beginner.I'm trying to do the login page and on clicking "Signin" button the page should navgiate to next page.
On clicking the button I tried to display an alert and its working.But I tried to navigate It shows Error as "app.component.ts (18,1): Cannot find name 'navigateUrl'." I want to know where the code causes error.

**Codes** :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl:'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

hello ={username:'yyy',password:'zzz'};
navigateUrl():void{
this.router.navigate(['/lazy.html']);

}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container text-center">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="text-center" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-t-20">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="text-center" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
   <div class="row margin-t-20">
    <input class="btn-primary text-center " type="button" (click)="navigateUrl()" value="Sign in" />
  </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a Angular path that reads `lazy.html` defined in your routes or do you want to redirect to actual HTML file?

Comment: For time being,I'm redirecting to the lazy.html file.

Comment: In that case I think you should use Angular's `navigateByUrl()` method. But it doesn't say why YOUR `navigateUrl` method isn't recognized... A few remarks: did you inject the `Router` service in AppComponent? Is the `templateUrl` property correct? (shouldn't it be `'./app.component.html'`?)

Comment: Already tried to use  navigateByUrl but it shows "Property 'router' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.Where as,Router service included  too in the app.component.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the 'Router' in the constructor. 
Also add a path of component from routing file this.router.navigate([<*path_from_routing_file*>]) function.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl:'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
constructor(private router: Router) {
}
hello ={username:'yyy',password:'zzz'};
navigateUrl() {
this.router.navigate(['/lazy']);

}
}
```

Comment: I'm tried giving like this "  this.router.navigate(['lazy.html']); " which is in the same folder, but on-clicking the sigin its showing "r: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'lazy.html'"